# How to activate RemoteFX on WIN7 Guest Hyper-V on WIN10 Host?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hyper-v, virtual-host, remotefx

Have Win7 Pro gen1 Hyper-V, all updates, RemoteFX added with 512Mb, SLAT Vt-x etc. OK AMD r9 280x 3GB videocard, Remote FX works on Win10 Guest but only with 512MB max, not working w 1GB video RAM. How to make it active on WIN7 Hyper-V guest Running/accessed from same host? Or if it only fork via RD, hot to connect properly to have RFX??
Cheers!